# Showing Navbar conditionally in a NextJS 14 project with app routing

Tags: next.js

In my NextJS 14.0 project, the routing structure is such that every route has its own directory with a `page.tsx` file. The homepage is rendered by a similar `page.txt` in the root directory, i.e. `/app`. This root location also has a `layout.txt` file that serves as a wrapper for the website. This is the file that displays both `components/Nabvar.tsx` and `./page.tsx`. The arrangement applies to all routes in various subfolders within this root, e.g., `./dashboard/page.tsx`, `./settings/page.tsx`, etc.

But there’s one route where I do not want the Navbar to show, `./login`.

I considered something like this in my `layout.tsx`:

```
type LayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  showNavbar: boolean;
}

const Layout = ({ children, showNavbar }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {showNavbar && <Navbar />}
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this doesn’t fly because this would mean importing `layout` into my `page.tsx` and using it thus:

```
<Layout showNavbar={false}>
      {/* Your page content goes here */}
</Layout>
```

Which isn’t possible with NextJS since it’s the `layout` component that calls the `page` component during compile and not the other way around.

Long story short, I need to control which pages to show the `navbar` on.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `<Navbar/>` a client component and use the `usePathname()` hook to check if the pathname matches the path you do not want the `<Navbar/>` to show on.

It would look something like this:

```js
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

function Navbar() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  if (pathname.includes("/unwantedPath")) return null;

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I would prefer not having to make it a client component.